# Layout problems when using video

Tags: css, html, video, layout

I'm having some layout issues with a design I'm doing here:
http://testing004.compoundeyedesign.com/

I'm trying to replicate the video/search box layout on Airbnb's homepage. In fact, I'm using their video in my page at the moment. [The problems I'm having are screengrabbed here.](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s4/sh/4a8872da-a960-4957-b309-b27f8d6553f8/a93cf45ce0ed455ff3cc2efd26d7ce61) But basically they are:

1. How do I get the purple box with the form to overlap the video or at least appear without a gap?
2. How do I keep the video from getting so tall on desktop browsers that the purple box and text below gets pushed below the fold?

I've experimented with the CSS and HTML, trying to improve what I have, but what you see now is the best I can get. Any pointers to push this in the right direction would be welcome.

Thanks! Russell

Answer (score 0):

If you want the purple box to be on top of the video, you need to use position: static;. Basically something like:

```css
#purplebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="video"></div>
  <div id="purplebar"></div>
</div>
```

If you are just trying to connect the two elements (remove the white) use your inspect element tool to find out what margin/padding is causing the difference, and remove it.

Comment: Woops! I'm so sorry for the non-response. I didn't get any notification about your reply. Very sorry. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. After some trial and error, your method seemed to work.